# tar compresses folder, but creates nested structure

Tags: directory, tar

I have the following folders on a linux machine

```
./myFolder
    ./tmp
    ./packages
    ./zips
    compress.sh
```

I run `tar -czf ./zips/someFile.tar.gz ./tmp/someFolder` from `compress.sh`. The folder is created, but the resulting nesting occurs inside the zip file:

> . -> tmp -> someFolder

How can I zip this file so that when I open it, it's just `someFolder`, and not `someFolder` inside `tmp`, inside `.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try following:

```
tar -czf ./zips/someFile.tar.gz -C ./tmp/ someFolder
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the parameter `-C` or `--directory`

```
tar -czf ./zips/someFile.tar.gz -C ./tmp someFolder
```

From `man tar`

```
-C, --directory DIR
      change to directory DIR
```

---

Example

```
% ls -og
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1    0 Mai 21 18:39 bar
drwxrwxr-x 2 4096 Mai 21 18:39 foo

tar -cvf ../sample.tar -C /home/user/tmp .

tar -tvf ../sample.tar 
drwxrwxr-x user/user 0 2015-05-21 18:39 ./
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 0 2015-05-21 18:39 ./bar
drwxrwxr-x user/user 0 2015-05-21 18:39 ./foo/
```

Comment: Nope, `-C` sets the current working directory, `someFolder` should be written relative to it.

Answer (score 3):

The `tar` command does not zip. Not even with the `-z` flag. However, it does collect a series of files/folders and optionally compress the result. To contrast, `zip` compresses each file and adds it to an archive. `zip` and `tar` use different compression algorithms.

The [man page for GNU tar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) shows the `-C` flag (`--directory`) to change directory, so you could do this

```
tar czfC zips/someFile.tar.gz tmp someFolder
```

You could also use the `--transform` option to remove the leading `tmp/`

```
tar czf zips/someFile.tar --transform 's#^tmp/##' tmp/someFolder
```